# datagridviewcombobox cell not shown saved data while entire row cells are displayed record from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

my DataGridview column cell having a combobox that can not shown particular database record, i am trying to solve in c#

first i bind datagridview and then bind combobox through coding.

and fetch data in combobox column from another table.

and save data in database through datagridview

and that datagridview also show the record of data from database but not shown in combobox.

please give me some logic idea what can i do

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please give detail description to better answer